# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified (Although all the files are there)

Tags: audio, wav, librosa, audio-converter, audiosegment

I am trying to make an audio converter to convert audio files to WAV format.

I am getting an error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` where it says the specified files are not there although I can clearly see they are there and the program is able to pick up the WAV file also and operating on the WAV file but is giving me error for the other formatted files....How to resolve this?

I am attaching some sample audio files for testing purposes and the code is provided below.

Sample audio files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xcJXTggzVy9irsH_oArAYptcRKZ93sLF?usp=sharing

```
import os
from playsound import playsound
from pydub import AudioSegment
from tqdm import tqdm
from glob import glob
from IPython.display import display,Audio
import librosa
import librosa.display


def create_dir(base,ext):
    _path=os.path.join(base,ext)
    if not os.path.exists(_path):
        os.mkdir(_path)
    return _path


f = []
wav_list = []
dir_list = os.listdir("C:/Users/MD. REZUWAN HASAN/Desktop/Jupyter files/BAI/data/")
out = create_dir(os.getcwd(),"All WAV Outputs")

#print(dir_list)


for i in dir_list:
    if i == '.ipynb_checkpoints' or i == 'Any2Wav Converter.ipynb' or i =="All WAV Outputs":
        pass
    else:
        #print(i)
        frmt = i[-4:]
        file_name = i[:-4]        
        #print(frmt)

        if frmt == ".wav":
            wav_list.append(i)
            sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(i)
            sound.export(f"All WAV Outputs/{file_name}.wav", format="wav")

        elif frmt == ".mp3" or frmt == ".MP3":
            sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(i)
            sound.export(f"All WAV Outputs/{file_name}.wav", format="wav")

        elif frmt == ".aac":
            sound = AudioSegment.from_file(i,"aac")
            sound.export(f"All WAV Outputs/{file_name}.wav", format="wav")
                        
        elif frmt == ".m4a":
            sound = AudioSegment.from_file(i,"m4a")
            sound.export(f"All WAV Outputs/{file_name}.wav", format="wav")
            
        elif frmt == ".mp4":
            sound = AudioSegment.from_file(i,"mp4")
            sound.export(f"All WAV Outputs/{file_name}.wav", format="wav")
            
        elif frmt == ".wma":
            sound = AudioSegment.from_file(i,"wma")
            sound.export(f"All WAV Outputs/{file_name}.wav", format="wav")
            
        elif frmt == ".ogg":
            sound = AudioSegment.from_ogg(i)
            sound.export(f"All WAV Outputs/{file_name}.wav", format="wav")
            
        elif frmt == ".flv":
            sound = AudioSegment.from_flv(i)
            sound.export(f"All WAV Outputs/{file_name}.wav", format="wav")

        else:
            pass


print()
if len(wav_list) == 0:
    print("No wav files")
else:
    print((wav_list))
```